# How to setup HLS and DVR functionality and read it?

Tags: html, nginx, stream, http-live-streaming

I want to create an audio stream live with the DVR functionality.

In my player I want to listen live or seek the past stream (few minutes ago).

I use nginx to serve the hls stream.
How to setup the DVR functionality? Do I use a specific module in nginx for live stream and past stream with a param like past.m3u8?seek=timestamp

I'm also looking for a web player in html5 and fallback in flash to read the live stream and can seek the past.m3u8 stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've setup nginx with this config:

```
    location /hls {
        # Serve HLS fragments
        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }
        root /tmp;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    }
```

I create hls stream with avconv.

```
    avconv -i [input] -vn -sn -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 64k -hls_time 10 /path/to/hls/playlist.m3u8
```

To read this stream I use clipr player who permits to seek the stream.